# Bringing the color palette of two pictures closer to each other using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I have a picture (rectangle in the center) and would like to tune color of it to minimize the color difference with background. I've changed brightness and contrast, but can't get better match.
[image]

Or if it will be easier: I have two pictures of the same size, but one of them is less detailed. Maybe there is a way to transfer colors "pixel by pixel" from one picture to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible method, although not perfect it, it's a good start. Further manual adjustments may be required.

1. Make sure both images are on their own layer, and select the top one
2. Do *Image > Adjustments > Match color*
3. In the Match Color dialog, set the source to the current image file, and set the layer to the background layer that you want to match it to.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It seems I've done this.

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked for you.